# Return value from Geocode Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geocode

I'm using the react-geocode api to get coordinates from a string address (like 1234 home street, etc.). So far, this is my code.

```
async function ConvertAddress(address) {
      if (address !== "") {
        Geocode.fromAddress(address, resolve).then(
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
              const center = { lat: lat, lng: lng}; // if I console logged center from here, it would work fine.
              return center;


            },
            (error) => {
              alert("ConvertAddress error:", error);
            }
            
        );
      }
    }
```

However, I'm not sure how to access "center" from outside this function (such as from another function). I've tried this:

```
console.log("ConvertAddress test", ConvertAddress(data[0]));
```

And it returns this:

```
ConvertAddress test 
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: undefined
​
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

Can I have some help with returning center in such a way that I can call it without it being undefined? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding an await in front of your ConverAddress in the console.log its an async function

Comment: const is block level scope. So create a variable outside the function with global scope and assign the center value to it

Comment: Async alone willn't make it synchronous,  use await before Geocode.fromAddress(address, resolve).then()

Comment: @ColinHale If I add await at the topmost line, it doesn't do anything. I tried adding it in front of Geocode.fromAddress, but that just changed the promise to <Pending>. If that was not what you meant, could you please write out the code for this? Thanks.

Comment: async function ConvertAddress(address) {
      if (address !== "") {
       var addressResult = await Geocode.fromAddress(address, resolve).then(
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
              const center = { lat: lat, lng: lng}; // if I console logged center from here, it would work fine.
              return center;
            },
            (error) => {
              return "error in results"
            }
        );
      }
    } try this

Comment: @Suresh it says "pending" for the promise. Also, addressResult and center both aren't used. Am I supposed to do more with them?

Comment: can we have any jsfiddle link to look into it

Comment: along with above shared code, use this and check addressResult .then(function(result) {
   console.log(result)
})

Comment: async function ConvertAddress(address) {
      if (address !== "") {
       var addressResult = await Geocode.fromAddress(address, resolve).then(
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
              const center = { lat: lat, lng: lng}; // if I console logged center from here, it would work fine.
              return center;
            },
            (error) => {
              return "error in results"
            }
        );
  addressResult.then(function(result){ 
   console.log(result);
  }) 
      }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
async function coordinateGenerator(address) {
      if (address !== "") {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          Geocode.fromAddress(address).then( 
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
              resolve([lat, lng]);
            },
            (error) => {
              alert(error);
              reject("Request failed");
            }
        );
        })
      }
    }
```

Then call it with:

```
const center = await coordinateGenerator(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async function ConvertAddress(address) {
      if (address !== "") {
       var addressResult = await Geocode.fromAddress(address, resolve).then(
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
              const center = { lat: lat, lng: lng}; // if I console logged center from here, it would work fine.
              return center;
            },
            (error) => {
              return "error in results"
            }
        );
        addressResult.then(function(result){ 
            console.log(result);
        }) 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. However, I do get this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: addressResult.then is not a function

Comment: can we have a jsfiddle with test code. So that we can see the result.